# Search Engine bots not found jquery

Tags: javascript, search-engine

I used *onerror* on sites  in order to save the javascript error logs.

Sometimes I find error logs which have been robots (google bot, bing bot), such as 
*ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $*.

While there is no errors by human users, each site is functioning properly.

The scripts in the head section:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular-aria.min.js" >
```

etc. Why? Sometimes shutdown the googleapis.com? Wrong place or order for scripts tag?

Comment: Hi, have You solved this problem?

Comment: @user712092 only skip bots by $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] (Googlebot, bingbot)